# Angular CLI adding hashed code internally in vendor.js file while running the build

Tags: angular-cli

When I am running the npm run build then the Angular CLI is giving me the 5 different bundled files like `main.js`, `Inline.js`, `polyfills.js`, `styles.js`, `vendor.js`

So inside the vendor.js file I can see something like `main.234bhasd42341234` and because of this the file is not getting render properly. It gives unexpected token error.

Let me know If anyone is having any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a gulp task issue. If we hash any file with gulp it check the refrence of every occurrence of a text and if its match then it will add a hash code to it.So I rewrite my gulp task again and its solved my problem.